# How do I set UIButton to go to the previous screen?

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I have a help screen that can be accessed from any other screen. The only button there is a "back" arrow. Right now it always goes back to the main screen. However, I need it to go back to which ever screen that was before it. I've hunted through stackoverflow and google but no luck.

**EDIT**
snippet of the code I'm using now:

```
appViewController *homeView = [[appViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
homeView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:homeView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? If so, consider pushing the help screen, then your back button can simply call `popViewControllerAnimated:YES` on the navigation controller to go back to the previous screen.

Comment: added a snippet so you can see what I'm doing the "appViewControll" is my home screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the modal view controller that is being presented right now, make it dismiss itself when clicking the home button:

```
- (void)buttonClicked
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: winner winner chicken dinner! This even solved a few other questions I had that I have been working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On button click You can use.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you: [How to navigate previous screen from camera view in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151026/how-to-navigate-previous-screen-from-camera-view-in-iphone)
Its about navigation and how to remove the last screen.

Or use this in the click event of button.Create an instance of the view controller to be opened

```
          EnterNameController *newEnterNameController = [[EnterNameController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"EnterName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
          [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I edited my question with a snippet of the code I'm using now. I need it to go the the previous screen no matter where the user is in the app.

Comment: why is that initWithNibName as null?

Comment: ok give the nib name of the view controller you want to display with the click of the button in the initWithNibName and then check

Comment: won't that specify the view I want to return to? Since there are multiple screens I may not know which screen they were before view the help screen.

Comment: ok,then do like this [self.view removeFromSuperview] .it will remove the top view from the screen and you will get to the next view you previously viewed